# php session_set_cookie_params() is not working in mobile chrome browser

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I am using the below code in my application. It works perfectly in a desktop browser. However when I am using a mobile browser the session does not work or not show any results:

```
<?php
function set-cookie-params($life,$path,$domain,$secure,$httpOnly){
    session_set_cookie_params($life,$path,$domain,$secure,$httpOnly);
    session_name('log-user');
    session_start();
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

use session_start(); in first line of your php page always

```
 session_start();
 ..
 ..
 ..
function set-cookie-params($life,$path,$domain,$secure,$httpOnly){
    session_set_cookie_params($life,$path,$domain,$secure,$httpOnly);
    session_name('log-user');
    session_start();
}
```

?>